# iOS FB SDK Incoming URL for apprequests is missing ref=notif, request_ids, app_request_type

Tags: ios, facebook-app-requests

I am using iOS FB SDK (baked in Parse F/W) to send app request invites using

`[facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:nil]`;]

The requests are being sent correctly and also appear on the invitee's account.
When I click on the request, the Facebook app correctly starts my app.
At this point, I am checking for incoming URL to process and get request_ids etc.
The sample code on FB (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/) says the incoming URL should be of following format

```
fb480369938658210://authorize&expires_in=3600&access_token=xyz&target_url=http://m.facebook.com/apps/friendsmashsample?fb_source=notification&request_ids=abc&ref=notif&app_request_type=Duser_to_user
```

However, I am receiving it like this

```
fb123456789123456://authorize?expires_in=86400&access_token=BAADiMgKGSZB8BAD3ZCeZAGNkm7d8tGuNZAKuq5nThbNTdiZA1ZBFcp1bhIKp1cFvwDsOPZCZBIgowSwRkBnZARF5tBsyWHk0yLukZAK8ubNZA4ZCbkyQg619cg9v0SMqsaBzgwNbQZCdPZBSLoYwZDZD&
target_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fappcenter%2F123456789123456
```

So there are missing components here like request_ids, ref=notif etc.

Does anything obvious looks to be missing here?

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future users, I had to set up the Mobile Site URL as per this bug filed with Facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/465760136778889/

Ridiculous, but it works. Hope this is resolved. Not sure why they have this dependency.

Comment: This is still undocumented, and cost me many hours until I found this post.  I have filed a bug to have them update the docs.